# After moving my site, sub-menus are not showing

Tags: css, sub-menu

After moving a WordPress site to a new host, my sub-menus on the main nav are not dropping down on hover. I notice in the Source file that the code for all the sub-menus is there but is greyed out.

When I do an inspect, the container for the sub-menus is not present. I've looked through CSS and it looks like the js is also there. Not sure what to do.

Also, on the WooCommerce Cart page ONLY, the drop downs are working! Go figure. So I'm just not sure where in the site to look next.
http://bartlettsfarm.com

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, your header is being wrapped in the div with the class "page-wrap", which should go around the whole page (that's what is does on the working WooCommerce page).

If you go into your inspector and uncheck "overflow:hidden" on the div with the class 'page-wrap', the menu starts working.

Maybe check your header and footer PHP files to make sure your opening and closing tags for the page wrap are correct.